# Administrator permission for certain programs

Tags: windows-7-x64, wampserver, user-permissions

Each time I open wampserver in windows 7 it opens the user access control dialog for administrator permission. Can I stop it from asking by adding it to some list of trusted publishers?

Comment: Nope. You need to have admin privileges to bind to port 80, and UAC is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is User Account Control (UAC). UAC doesn't allow white listing a particular application. You have to disable it to get rid of these messages.

To know more about UAC or to diable it see http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm